# How many times can a list be split in a way that every element on the left is smaller than every element on the right?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

For example if the list is: [2,1,2,5,7,6,9] there's 3 possible ways of splitting:
[2,1,2] [5,7,6,9]
[2,1,2,5] [7,6,9]
[2,1,2,5,7,6] [9]

I'm supposed to calculate how many times the list can be split in a way that every element on the left is smaller than every element on the right. So with this list, the output would be 3. 
Here's my current solution:

```
def count(t):
    c= 0
    for i in range(len(t)):
        try:
            if max(t[:i]) < min(t[i:]):
                c+=1
        except:
            continue

    return c
```

The above code does the right thing, but it's not of O(n) time complexity.
How could I achieve the same result, but faster?

Comment: if you have 4 elements in the left and they are all smaller than the right ones, adding a new element doesn't require calculating the max value of all 5 elements, just check the new added element.

Comment: I am curious, what do you think is the time complexity of your solution ? @Kodtld

Comment: So far the time complexity would remain the same, unless you find a similar way for the min() side as well.

Comment: Are you sure that a faster result is achievable in the first place?

Comment: @HatimZahid not OP but I believe it's ~ O(`n²`) since for each iteration `i` of the for loop you need to scan two slices of the `n`-length list with `max` (O(`i`) time complexity) and `min` (O(`n-i`) time complexity).

Comment: @jfaccioni Yes it's O(n²). The list that you scan, just for max would be of length 1+2+3+4+...+N and Thats the Gaussian sum formula which is equivalent to (N²+N)/2 where N² dominates for large N. And for min it's the reverse but the same number of operations and as such the same time complexity.

Comment: @haxor789 Or you could just say that in every loop iteration, the whole list gets processed (by min and max combined).

Comment: @KellyBundy But that would be sooo obvious (shit I missed that completely). Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: @jfaccioni You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my final answer:

```
def count(t):
    c = 0
    maxx = max(t)
    right = [0]*len(t)
    left = [0]*len(t)
    maxx = t[0]
   
    for i in range(0, len(t)):
    
        if maxx >= t[i]:
            left[i] = maxx
            
        if maxx < t[i]:
            maxx = t[i]
            left[i] = maxx
             
    minn = t[-1] 
    for i in range(len(t)-1,-1,-1):
        if minn <= t[i]:
            right[i] = minn
            
        if minn > t[i]:
            minn = t[i]
            right[i] = minn
           
    for i in range(0, len(t)-1):
        if left[i] < right[i+1] :
            c += 1
 
    return c
```

Answer (score 7):

Compute all prefix maxima and suffix minima in linear time. And combine them in linear time.

```
from itertools import accumulate as acc
from operator import lt

def count(t):
    return sum(map(lt,
                   acc(t, max),
                   [*acc(t[:0:-1], min)][::-1]))
```

Jacques requested a benchmark:

```
1444.6 ms  Jacques_Gaudin
   5.0 ms  Kelly_Bundy
1424.5 ms  Jacques_Gaudin
   4.4 ms  Kelly_Bundy
1418.2 ms  Jacques_Gaudin
   4.7 ms  Kelly_Bundy
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLbbtswDH3XV/ClqJR5Qbx0wyDML30psH1CEBiqLTcCdPFkKlu@PqPkJXW6Ti8CyXPIw8t4wkPw269jPJ@HGBygcdogGDeGiH8tViIGdcQQ7HQJqq5LLlmFGtSUrRkXRh0VhniBWWSs1wP80Nae2sfk@xNHIRnQixpT9DAlx50aucWquN88Ss2xAqd@i3fju1VB7ORGfqz3BDRe7HcyG0LMxb@r7mfSU/ukUm/8tb4ZwAdqU16UbFjxHyuwesCWSkID1kxIlKKA/oLoKojm5UAQ4wmyeSWU8K@DsRo4zcyBbOC4HsPIhQDlezjKaxNUv0Ca5kqXNx0uVOTiR/EP9durjlvqUl5GLpnXtP9ld/ChgXq5pI6xIfluonS74r@d6byZxZIrtmcML@OLyr9oXn/aPnymnQx0HjkZkLo56Qq2WUA@OKLMd8etcs@9kgVSFuCTe9axqfMYxmg88vu7L@t6ADfBPdwBL/wV1HpL6Exbt61XTretOJ//AA)):

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import accumulate as acc
from operator import lt

def Kelly_Bundy(t):
    return sum(map(lt,
                   acc(t, max),
                   [*acc(t[:0:-1], min)][::-1]))

def Jacques_Gaudin(t):
    if not t: return 0

    v, left_max = list(t), max(t)
    c, right_min = 0, left_max
    while (item := v.pop()) and v:
        if item == left_max:
            left_max = max(v)
        if item < right_min:
            right_min = item
        if left_max < right_min:
            c += 1
    return c

funcs = [
    Jacques_Gaudin,
    Kelly_Bundy,
]

t = list(range(12345))
for func in funcs * 3:
  time = timeit(lambda: func(t), number=1)
  print('%6.1f ms ' % (time * 1e3), func.__name__)
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is linear time. `max` and `min` are O(n). Also, not sure if slicing is a good idea since it creates a copy of the list.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I mean the idea apparently is that you once create a list of both the maximum and the minimums by going through the list comparing the neighbors. So it's essentially 3*N which would be a complexity of N rather than N².

Comment: @haxor789: How do you get 3 * N? The max and min of the left and right respectively are computed for N steps, so I get O(N²). Am I missing something? Also the number of lists created makes me very dubious. Anyone has time for a benchmark?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I guess the idea is that both max and min are computed in one iteration over the list where you have just one comparison between an element and it's next in line, so that would be of complexity N. You'd got that twice once for min and once for max. And then you have another loop via that map that combines the results of min and max, that would be the third time you loop. But you never loop inside the loop so it's just 3*N rather than N² or worse, right? But sure the list creation might still ruin that. The reverse list would be 4*N but that still doesn't matter.

Comment: @Jacques Gaudin `accumulate` calls `min`/`max` always just with **two** values, so each call is O(1).

Comment: @haxor789 Yes but a list creation is O(n) by itself.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Yes but unless the list creation happens within the loop it would just add a complexity of N to it which would not increase with N so it's still in N, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jacques Gaudin Added a little benchmark. Enjoy :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy @haxor789 I get you r point, the bit I was confused with was `[*acc(t[:0:-1], min)]` but you're right it's linear. Can we reduce the number of lists created and improve readability?

Comment: @Jacques Gaudin I just realized that your own test case, despite having a million values, is pretty much certain to not have *any* valid splits. So that's rather uninteresting and unrealistic. If all real cases were like that, I'd just write `def count(t): return 0` :-). Perhaps the most realistic usage is something like the question's example: Not strictly increasing, but still with an upward trend, allowing splits every now and then. I don't want to guess there, though, it's rather the OP's job to tell us how their real data looks like...

Comment: @KellyBundy You're definitely right, the population and trend of the list matters. I somehow like this problem. Nice solution BTW although I would struggle to read it in 6 months time!

Comment: @Jacques Gaudin I had a maybe more readable version, but unintentionally swiped (doing this all on my phone) and bang... code gone. Might do again if I can dig out my laptop.

Comment: @KellyBundy Woowww you're doing that on your phone! I find that rather impressive!

Comment: I think `reversed(acc(t[:0:-1], min))` would be equivalent to `[*acc(t[:0:-1], min)][::-1]` in this case.

Comment: Or even `reversed(acc(reversed(t), min))`. I didn't benchmark it, but it's more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

My answer turned out to be very similar to kelly's above - we both calculate the mins and maxs for valid split points then check the condition on each split.

I'm around +50% slower than Kelly's as it's not fully functional as Kelly's is.

```
from itertools import accumulate as acc
from typing import List
def paddy3118(lst: List[int]) -> int:
    
    # min of RHS for any split
    min_from_r = list(acc(lst[::-1], min))[::-1]
    # max of LHS for any split
    max_from_l = list(acc(lst, max))

    # Condition for valid split
    return sum(max_from_l[split] < min_from_r[split+1]
               for split in range(len(lst) - 1))
```

The following function can generate interesting test data, (try `count` == `swap` for larger `count` arguments):

```
def _gen_swap(count, swaps):
    ans = list(range(count))
    for i in range(swaps):
        s = random.randint(0, count - 2)
        ans[s], ans[s+1] = ans[s+1], ans[s]
    return ans
```

Comment: Nice test data generator. I'll probably use that when I redo my benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

my attempt:

```
def count(t):
    max_el = t[0]
    min_el = min(t[1:])
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(t)-1):
        if t[i] == min_el:
            min_el = min(t[i+1:])
        if max_el < t[i]:
            max_el = t[i]
        if max_el < min_el:
            res +=1
    return res
```

Pretty straightforward, only compute the max/min if it could be different.

Comment: If the list is [1,2,3,4,5] for example, that wouldn't result in the right answer.

Comment: Still only O(n^2).

Comment: You'd need to swap out the 1st and 3rd if condition to fix that problem. Because you're already changing the minimum before you checked it.

Comment: @KellyBundy Is it O(n²)? I mean in the worst case like a fully ordered list, it would be O(n²) but it could also be O(n) in the best case.

Comment: @Kodtld, you are right. should be fixed now.

Comment: @KellyBundy, you are right. But it should be faster in most cases